# object literal not defined unless wrapped in jQuery onready; need ideas for debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery

Adopted some javascript code that I'm rearranging into smaller files to make it more managable; I'm never been a full-time javascript engineer but have worked with it for awhile but don't feel super comfortable with it.

I have an object literal that handles most of our controller level activities for our site. We've rearranged the code and put it in different files but there's one specific object where I'm getting an undefined error. Looking at the load order of the files, it comes in before the jQuery piece. Also wrapping this object literal in another jQuery onready wrapper fixes the problem. If I check via somethign like this:

```
if (typeof arc.event_handler === "undefined"){
 alert("something is undefined");
}else{
 alert("something is defined");
}
```

then with jQuery onready wrapping, it is defined but without it is undefined. Like (I know that this code will work either with or without the jQuery onload)

```
// file-1.js 
var arc={};
$(document).ready(function(){
  arc.event_handler={
    do_something: function(){
      alert('do something');
    }
  }
});
```

and then later in different file

```
// later in load order z-file.js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (typeof arc.event_handler === "undefined"){
    alert("something is undefined");  
  }else{
    alert("something is defined");
   }


  $('.some').on('click',function(){
     arc.event_handler.do_something();
  });
});
```

I'm a little bit at a loss what could causing this behavior. My understanding is that even if an external file, the part in the jQuery onready should essentially cause it to wait until these other pieces are loaded. I'm probably not getting something really simple but wanted to see if there were any ideas about what next to look at next?

thx in advance

Comment: No, jQuery.ready does wait for the DOM, not for all scripts. How do you load them, and in which order?

Comment: Is your code above distributed over two files (the 2 ready sections)? If no, it should work

Comment: yes, distributed over two files. the above code is the working version. Ideally, I'd like to remove the jQuery wrapper around the arc.event_handler object literal but getting undefined.

Comment: In your code you need to check like this: if(typeof arc.event_handler === undefined){ } since undefined is a keyword in javascript

Comment: Should be no problem. Show us how those scripts are included in your page

Comment: @Ashwin: No, he uses the `typeof` operator very well. And, `undefined` is *no* keyword

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure it's something unrelated to this code. It seems extremely unlikely but is it possible that the jQuery piece is firing before this file is loaded? I think it's something with another piece of code maybe a redeclaration but it works fine when I add the jQuery onready wrapper. Very frustrating

Comment: Yes, that is possible of course, depending on how you load the file. Show us the inclusion syntax!

Comment: As requested above, please show how you're loading both your own scripts, and jQuery

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/second.js"></script>
```

first.js:

```
arc = {
    event_handler: {
        do_something: function(){
            alert('do something');
        }
    }
};
```

second.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.some').on('click', arc.event_handler.do_something);
});
```

Comment: thx, so I agree that that should be working; I'm just baffled as to why it's not working. Honestly, I was hoping it was just me not knowing something obvious. Let me trying to start commenting out parts. Might just leave the onready call but so ugly. Thx for help